# How can I edit the last n lines in a file?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

Is there a command that will allow me to edit the last n lines in a file?
I have several files, that all have a different number of lines inside. But I would like to modify the last n lines in each file. The goal is to replace commas with semicolons in the last n lines. But only in the very last n lines.

I do not want to delete any lines, I just want to replace every comma with a semicolon in the last n lines in each file.

Using the sed command I am able to replace the very last line with this command. As described here:
[How can I remove text on the last line of a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65512/how-can-i-remove-text-on-the-last-line-of-a-file)

But this only enables me to modify the very last line, and not the last n number of lines.

Comment: Simply using `sed '24,$s/,/:/g' filename`  where `24` is the starting line`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To replace commas with semicolons on the last n lines with `ed`:

```
n=3
ed -s input <<< '$-'$((n-1))$',$s/,/;/g\nwq'
```

Splitting that apart:

- `ed -s` = run ed silently (don't report the bytes written at the end)
- `'$-'` = from the end of the file (`$`) minus ...
- `$((n-1))` = n-1 lines ...
- ( `$' ... '` = quote the rest of the command to protect it from the shell )
- `,$s/,/;/g` = ... until the end of the file (`,$`), search and replace all commas with semicolons.
- `\nwq` = end the previous command, then save and quit

To replace commas with semicolons on the last n lines with `sed`:

```
n=3
sed -i "$(( $(wc -l < input) - n + 1)),\$s/,/;/g" input
```

Breaking that apart:

- `-i` = edit the file "in-place"
- `$(( ... ))` = do some math:
- `$( wc -l < input)` = get the number of lines in the file
- `-n + 1` = go backwards n-1 lines
- `,\$` = from n-1 lines until the end of the file:
- `s/,/;/g` = replace the commas with semicolons.

Comment: Can replace `wc -l < input` with `wc -l input`. Should be faster by a few nanoseconds :)

Comment: except that `wc -l input` outputs the filename as well; we only want the line count

Comment: The first advice with ed is fine and simple.

Comment: I actually ended up getting help from a completely different side. This resulted in this odd piece of code, that does the trick but is long and strange. I guess this is some of weird things you can end up with when to piece together a solution. Anyways yours is prettier , shorter and less complicated than my own: The code here also worked:

Comment: cat input.file | sed 's/,/,\n/g' | sed -n '1!G;h;$p' | awk -v n=2 'NR<=n{gsub(",",";",$0)} {print}' | sed -n '1!G;h;$p' | sed '/^\s*$/d' > output.file

Answer (score 8):

Solution using `tac` and `sed` to replace every comma with a semicolon in the last 50 lines of file.txt:

```
tac file.txt | sed '1,50s/,/;/g' | tac
```

Answer (score 6):

With GNU `head` and a Bourne-like shell:

```
n=20
{ head -n -"$n"; tr , ';'; } < file 1<> file
```

We're overwriting the file over itself. That's OK here for a byte-to-byte transliteration but wouldn't necessarily if the modification implies changing the size of the file (in which case, you'd want to replace `1<> file` with `> other-file && mv other-file file` for instance).

Comment: [Here's docs for `1<>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_07), which I was unfamiliar with. Also, [`sponge`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sponge) from [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) is a good tool for pipelines where you want to overwrite your input.

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume we want to replace the last `7` lines of the following sequence with shell script and GNU implementation of `sed`:

```
$ seq 20
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
```

**Step 1**: lets get the last line number of sequence like the following. Take a look at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4503/155643) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4651458/4838962):

```
$ lastLine=`seq 20|sed -n '$='`

$ echo $lastLine 
20
```

**Step 2**: lets set the number of lines (at the end of sequence) we intend to edit:

```
$ numberOfLines=7

$ echo $numberOfLines 
7
```

**Step 3**: lets calculate the start line based on previous variables, like the following. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8386731/4838962):

```
$ startLine=`expr $lastLine - $numberOfLines + 1`

$ echo $startLine 
14
```

**Step 4**: Now, we can replace the last 7 lines of sequence with something else, like the following. Take a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/508174/407516):

```
$ seq 20|sed -e "$startLine,+$numberOfLines{s/[12]/WoW/}"
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
WoW4
WoW5
WoW6
WoW7
WoW8
WoW9
WoW0
```

Step 4 is using section 4.4 of [sed man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.txt) which says:

```
'ADDR1,+N'
     Matches ADDR1 and the N lines following ADDR1.
```

Step 4, also is using **double-quotes** as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/508174/407516).

---

Well, the 4 steps are unnecessary if we use the [answer of Gohu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/372490/155643) like this:

```
$ seq 20 |tac|sed -e '1,7{s/[12]/WoW/}'|tac
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
WoW4
WoW5
WoW6
WoW7
WoW8
WoW9
WoW0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `tail` and pipe to sed:

`tail -n 20 file | sed 's/,/;/g'`

This works on the file for the last 20 lines. If you want to have thee canges direct to the file use:

`tail -n 20 file | sed -i 's/,/;/g'`